# reproduce task dependencies in actual practise

Tags: scala, sbt

[the sbt task documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#tasks-with-inputs) shows an example of usage dependencies. It is very simple, artificial but it works! So I reproduced it in my `project/scala.build` without problem.

Note that I choose global scope to make tasks available for any project and any configuration

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestBuild extends Build {
  lazy val sampleTask = taskKey[Int]("A sample task")
  lazy val intTask = taskKey[Int]("An int task")

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    intTask := 1 + 2 ,
    sampleTask := intTask.value + 1
  )

}
```

Now I'm trying to do something useful and enrich existing sbt key definitions with task that collects compiled class names

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import sbt.inc.Analysis
import xsbti.api.ClassLike
import xsbt.api.Discovery.{isConcrete, isPublic}

object TestBuild extends Build {
  lazy val debugAPIs = taskKey[List[String]]("list of all top-level definitions")

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    debugAPIs := getAllTop( compile.value )
  )

  private def getAllTop(analysis : Analysis) : List[String] =
    Tests.allDefs(analysis).toList collect {
      case c : ClassLike if isConcrete(c) && isPublic(c) => c.name
    }
}
```

Now I get error from sbt:

```
Reference to undefined setting: 

  {.}/*:compile from {.}/*:debugAPIs (/home/sbt/project/build.scala:11)
```

So I have two questions:

- How should I define debugAPIs properly so that it task would be available for all projects and all configurations?
- How can I reproduce this error in synthetic configuration?

I'm more interested in the second question actually. I look for deep understanding of how sbt works because I'd like to write a plugin for it.

Comment: What do you mean by "synthetic configuration" ?

Comment: minimal possible meaningless scala.build file that does nothing more that just reproduces error "Reference to undefined setting".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access a key value without a proper [Scope](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html).

The documentation gives us some hint here.

> By default, all the keys associated with compiling, packaging, and
>   running are scoped to a configuration and therefore may work
>   differently in each configuration. The most obvious examples are the
>   task keys compile, package, and run; but all the keys which affect
>   those keys (such as source-directories or scalac-options or
>   full-classpath) are also scoped to the configuration.

Let's first focus on a very simple example, which maybe doesn't make much sense, but illustrates the problem. Lets assume that you want to redefine the `compile` task to itself.

```
override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq (
    compile := { compile.value }
)
```

Running this in SBT will give you an error, which is more or less like this

```
[error]   {.}/*:compile from {.}/*:compile (/tmp/q-23723818/project/Build.scala:12)
[error]      Did you mean compile:compile ?
```

We didn't specify the scope so SBT picked some defaults. The project was set to `ThisBuild` (meaning no specific project) and configuration set to `Global`. The setting was undefined in that context. However it's important to understand that a key is not a setting. The key can exist without scope, but the value of a key is attached to a scope. Note also that, if SBT won't find the value in the requested scope it can delegate to other scopes, but this is another topic.

How can we check this? Turns out that quite simple. Let's ignore the error, and let the SBT start.

If you type `inspect compile` you'll see that the inspect will look in `compile:compile`, where the value is defined. We can force it to look in a specific scope, e.g. `inspect {.}/*:compile`, will look in scope that gave us the error.

```
> inspect {.}/*:compile
[info] No entry for key.
```

Indeed it's undefined.

How to solve the issue? You have to give SBT the scope you're looking for. Naively you could try to add a configuration scope.

```
// this will NOT work
override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq (
    compile in Compile := { (compile in Compile).value }
)
```

Well but there is no global compile, there is only compile per project. You could overcome the issue by not overriding global settings, but the settings for a specific project, and specifying `Compile` configuration there.

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).settings(Seq(
  compile in Compile := {(compile in Compile).value}
): _*)
```

This would work,but what if you want to get the compile value regardless of where it is? This is where [ScopeFilter](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#getting-values-from-multiple-scopes) comes in handy. Back to your original example. I assume you want to get compile's Analysis object from all the projects.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import sbt.inc.Analysis
import xsbti.api.ClassLike
import xsbt.api.Discovery.{isConcrete, isPublic}

object TestBuild extends Build {

  val debugAPIs = taskKey[Seq[String]]("list of all top-level definitions")

  val compileInAnyProject = ScopeFilter(inAnyProject, inConfigurations(Compile))

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    debugAPIs := { 
      getAllTop(compile.all(compileInAnyProject).value)
    }
  )

  private def getAllTop(analyses : Seq[Analysis]) : Seq[String] =
    analyses.flatMap { analysis =>
      Tests.allDefs(analysis) collect { case c : ClassLike if isConcrete(c) && isPublic(c) => c.name }
    }

}
```

What we created is a `ScopeFilter` filtering for any project, and in that projects for `Compile` configuration. Then we looked for all compile values.

You can configure the `ScopeFilter` to match your needs, and only filter for specific projects/configurations or even tasks. But the key to understand the problem is to remember that in SBT settings are always scoped.

#### Edit

You have asked how it comes that the `compile` is not defined globally but is available to every project. This is because there is [`Defaults.defaultSettings`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/sxr/Defaults.scala.html#339135) which define it. And each project include it. If you removed `super.settings` from your Build definition you'd see that among others `compile` is undefined.

And as if you should do it this way. Well overriding `settings` in your plugin is in general discouraged in [Plugin Best Practices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html). However I recommend that you read it, together with [Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Extending/Plugins.html) chapter. It should give you an idea of how to proceed.

You can also get multiple values from multiple scopes by defining new task returning them. For example to get analyses with a project, you could use following piece of code.

```
object TestBuild extends Build {

  val debugAPIs = taskKey[Seq[(String, String)]]("list of all top-level definitions")

  val compileInAnyProject = ScopeFilter(inAnyProject, inConfigurations(Compile))

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    debugAPIs := { 
      getAllTop(analysisWithProject.all(compileInAnyProject).value)
    }
  )

  lazy val analysisWithProject = Def.task { (thisProject.value, compile.value) }

  private def getAllTop(analyses : Seq[(ResolvedProject, Analysis)]) : Seq[(String, String)] =
    analyses.flatMap { case (project, analysis) =>
      Tests.allDefs(analysis) collect { case c : ClassLike if isConcrete(c) && isPublic(c) => (project.id, c.name) }
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to output analysis per configuration separately to check what classes are in them.
And what about scopes in the first example? They were defined globally so they were available globally, as I assume.
And compile is not defined globally and the problem lies in it.
But if compile is not defined globally how was it actually defined and become available for all projects? May be I may define debugAPIs in the same way?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it is more clear now. Just keep in mind, that keys are not settings, they are not scoped, only their values exist in scopes.